# How can I test/access companion object extension functions in Kotlin?

Tags: junit, kotlin, junit5, kotlin-extension

I have an Base64Util class with amongst others an extension function `decodeBase64ToByteArray` :

```
class Base64Util {
  companion object {
    fun String.decodeBase64ToByteArray(): ByteArray {
        return Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(this)
    }
  }
}
```

Now I would like to test my `Base64Util` via `Base64IUtilTest`. I can access non extension functions of course, but how can I access/test the `String.decodeBase64ToByteArray()` from `Base64UtilTest` ?

Comment: I would omit that `class` and `companion object`, so you basically only have a function inside an empty (or only `import` and `package` statements) `kt`-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply access *member extension functions* such as `decodeBase64ToByteArray` from outside. This is only possible if you get into the scope of the object it is defined in:

```
with(Base64Util.Companion){ //.Companion could be removed
    "123fsad123".decodeBase64ToByteArray()
}
```

It could make sense to define your util functions as top-level functions in a file `base64Utils.kt` for example. This way, they can be called in a static way without any issue.

Comment: Why lower case b in 'base64Utils.kt' ? Is that standard for util?